# Происхождение выражения "ну его"

Tags: фразеология, пунктуация

Помните, как говорила Масяна: "Ну(,) да и ну его".
Во-первых, внезапно возник вопрос: нужна ли тут запятая после первого "ну".
А во-вторых, интересна природа самого выражения. Ну его - что? У меня ощущение, что это какой-то урезанный вариант чего-то более длинного. Но вопрос: чего? Как эта фраза звучала изначально? Аналогию тут можно подобрать: "Ну и Бог с ним". Но она ничего не объясняет.
Буду благодарна за разъяснения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Ну" – это в том числе и "пусть".

*Употр. как выражение нетерпеливого побуждения, призыва к действию.* (Большой толковый словарь Кузнецова). Например: *Ну его к черту!* ~ Пусть идёт к черту.

Answer (score -1):

Позволю себе высказать некоторые соображения по поводу НУ ЕГО. Ну в данном случае может быть вариантом или искажением **НЫ**, т.е. **НУ**=**НЫ**.
Большой словарь русских поговорок (В.М.Мокиенко, Т.Г.Никитина, 2007) сообщает: **Выйти на ны. Сиб. Полностью разориться.** СРНГ 21, 322.
Кроме того, Русский матерный словарь приводит выражение: **Х^^-на-ны́! — (в нарративе) результат, противоположный ожиданиям**, - *мне это выражение случалось слышать изустно*.
Ещё есть разговорное словечко *ЗА***НЫ***КАТЬ*, означающее: **нехорошим образом изъять, присвоить**. Получается, что **НУ(НЫ) здесь типа восклицательное словцо, означающее что-то уничижительное по отношению к кому-либо**. Но этот ответ я предъявляю только как гипотезу. Хотелось бы узнать мнения других участников сайта.

Answer (score -2):

Это сокращение от матерного выражения *да ну его на х@@*.

Comment: это частный случай.  "Ну его к лешему" не "катит"?